# Site that works in IIS 7, will not work in IIS 7.5

Tags: frameworks, iis-7, asp.net-3.5, iis-7.5

We have a C# site that works fine in IIS 7, but when we try deploying it to another server (runnng 7.5) it stays in a loop and the login page does not appear. It just hangs.

There is no DB etc, just the page. Is there a differendce in the hanlders and modules from 7 to 7.5? all in the 3.5 framework

Thanks

Niall

Answer (score 0):

Run Fiddler when you fetch the page, so you can see if there's a redirect loop happening. This can commonly appear to be a hang.

ASP.NET's unfortunate cultural preference for external redirects means it's very easy to end up with situations like a login page that redirects to an error page that redirects to the login page that redirects to the error page... turn all your redirects and custom errors off for testing purposes. (And arguably, look to replace them with eg. transfers in any case; redirects have many usability problems too.)

Comment: Thanks, I shall try that now.